# Oracle dump to csv and keep NULL as empty string

Tags: oracle, dump

I have the following sql file:

```
SET COLSEP ';'
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET PAGESIZE 32766 -- Maximum number we can set.
                   -- i.e there will be duplication of headers. 
SET LINESIZE 32766 -- Maximum number we can set.SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TERM OFF
--SET TRIMS ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET UNDERLINE OFF

SPOOL dump_audit_table.csv

SELECT timestamp, PROXY_SESSIONID,sessionid FROM dba_audit_trail where rownum < 10;

set trimspool off
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
```

Which exports the following CSV:

```
TIMESTAMP          ;PROXY_SESSIONID; SESSIONID
04-29-2014 21:46:40;               ; 707304320
04-29-2014 21:46:40;               ; 707304320
04-29-2014 21:46:46;               ; 707452228
04-29-2014 21:46:46;               ; 707452228
04-29-2014 21:46:46;               ; 707452228
04-29-2014 21:46:46;               ; 707452228
```

My Problem is: PROXY_SESSIONID nulls are represented as `'         '` a string with column width of spaces. 
I could not find a way to completely terminate this. I would like the file to be exported in  the following way:

```
 04-29-2014 21:46:46;;707452228
```

e.g: `NULL` should be `;;` read: empty string! 
     `SESSIONID` should not have a leading space.

Comment: Did you find answer for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I normally make .csv files.
You should be able to open the file with Excel.

```
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 2048
COLUMN text format A2048
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TAB OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET TERMOUT ON

SPOOL dump_audit_table.csv

SELECT '"'||timestamp||'","'||PROXY_SESSIONID||'","'||sessionid||'"' text
FROM dba_audit_trail where rownum < 10;

SPOOL OFF
QUIT
```